# Why doesn't my function remove an element after a delay?

Tags: javascript, transition, fade

I'm struggling to make a notification show on press of a button and then hide after a time. Nearly all of the resources I found implement a solution based on jQuery, but I am not using a JS framework and am not willing to to so just for the sake of this. What I got so far:

```js
function notify() {
  var success = document.getElementById("success");

  success.innerHTML = 'ok';
  success.style.opacity = '1';
  setTimeout(function () {
    success.classList.add('fade');
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
#successposition {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
#success {
  z-index: 12;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(38, 213, 26, 0.5);
  padding: 15px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
#success.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s opacity;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="notify.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="notify()">click me</button>
    <div id="successposition"><div id="success"></div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sadly, this only shows the notification on click, but it never goes away. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inline styles override your class-based styles. Switch to just classes:

```js
function notify() {
  var success = document.getElementById("success");

  success.innerHTML = 'ok';
  success.classList.add('show'); // <-- HERE

  setTimeout(function () {
    success.classList.remove('show'); // <-- HERE
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
#successposition {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
#success {
  z-index: 12;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(38, 213, 26, 0.5);
  padding: 15px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s opacity; /* <-- HERE */
}
#success.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="notify.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="notify()">click me</button>
    <div id="successposition"><div id="success"></div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your code to work with one modification, I added !important to fade's opacity.

```
#success.fade {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  transition: 0.5s opacity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add !important to `.fade` it works beautifully

```
#success.fade {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  transition: 0.5s opacity;
}
```

```js
function notify() {
  var success = document.getElementById("success");

  success.innerHTML = 'ok';
  success.style.opacity = '1';
  setTimeout(function () {
    success.classList.add('fade');
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
#successposition {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
#success {
  z-index: 12;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(38, 213, 26, 0.5);
  padding: 15px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
#success.fade {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  transition: 0.5s opacity;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="notify.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="notify()">click me</button>
    <div id="successposition"><div id="success"></div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `!important` should be a last resort. It makes further work more difficult.